# AWS NLB is being created with internet-facing scheme

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes-ingress, amazon-eks, nginx-ingress

My main objective is to make my EKS pods accessible only through a VPN.

I've created an NLB to redirect requests to my EKS Ingresses. All EKS nodes are in private subnets, which I can have access to only through the VPN connection.

I installed using this `Chart.yaml`:

```yaml
dependencies:
  - name: ingress-nginx
    version: ~4.1.4
    repository: https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx
```

I installed the Nginx Ingress Controller with the values below:

```yaml
ingress-nginx:
  controller:
    ingressClassResource:
      default: true
    service:
      annotations:
        service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-backend-protocol: tcp
        service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type: nlb
        service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-scheme: internal
```

Even though I explicitly set the scheme to internal, this is the result:

[image]

I am unsure what I am missing, but I tried what they say [here](https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-load-balancer-controller/v2.2/guide/service/annotations/#lb-scheme).

Comment: Annotation looks correct. Have you checked the aws-load-balancer-controller logs? Did the NLB already exist before adding the annotation?

Comment: @jordanm i have only an ingress nginx controller, not an aws load balancer controller

Comment: The doc you linked in your question is for the aws-load-balancer-controller. tbh I didn't even know you could provision a NLB without it. You can install it as an EKS add-on: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/aws-load-balancer-controller.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm not super sure why but I had to add this annotation for the load balancer to become internal -
`service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-internal: "true"`. It is supposed to be deprecated according to https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-load-balancer-controller/v2.2/guide/service/annotations/#lb-scheme